# NTFS volume in an FAT32 partition?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, ntfs, format, fat32

I've just formatted my new external HDD from FAT32 to NTFS in Ubuntu, but then I noticed that the "partition type" shows as

`W95 FAT32 (LBA) (0x0c)`

while the volume shows (correctly) as an NTFS volume.

[image: Ubuntu gnome-disk-utility screenshot]

My question is whether there would be any problem with this arrangement, or if I should edit the partition type.

In case it is necessary or recommended to change the partition type, which type should I choose?

NB: I guess keeping the MBR partitioning scheme instead of changing it to GUID Partition Table is OK.

I've checked the disk under Windows, and it didn't find any problem with it. Under properties, it lists the filesystem as NTFS.

[image: Disk properties]

So far, the HDD is working fine under both Windows and Linux. Perhaps this is not an issue, but since I still don't get all the [differences between 'volume', 'partition', and 'drive'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87300), I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you unmounted and re-mounted the device? It may be using cached data.

Comment: I have unmounted and even physically disconnected the device. That's what prompted me to post a question.

Comment: As a USB device, that *could* be the partition type being returned by the USB->SATA controller. Which I would say probably isn't an issue. For an extra check, you could always mount it on Windows system and see if it works / reformat and see if that fixes it. (Since NTFS is a Microsoft file system)

Comment: Also, why are you  formatting an external drive with NTFS? Surely exFAT would be more suitable, or EXT4 if you only use *nix systems?

Comment: @Alastor thank you for your useful comments. I need to plug my HDD to both Linux and Windows systems. I'll check under Windows as you suggest.

Comment: I thought exFAT was more suitable for flash media such as memory sticks and memory cards rather than a hard disk where NTFS (if the user predominately uses Windows) would be a more suitable choice?